# Combining Event, Membership & Contacts into single report

Tags: civireport

So I can easily create a Search Builder for what I want, my challenge is creating a report that I can print an take to an event

Criteria:
Either registered for event
OR
A member of a specific group

From Contacts
Name, Email

From Membership
Status, End Date (if any)

From Event
Registration (if any)

The problem is that all the report templates are missing one or several of these items, or assume you only want event participants or current members.

Am I missing something or this is a known limitation?

Comment: What CMS do you use?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Drupal, you can create a View that shows all that data. When you build the View, on the right click Advanced and in Relationships add the CiviCRM tables so you can show both Event & Membership data.
Add the Drupal Views Data Export module so you can download the results and print it.

Comment: There is also Views PDF

Comment: Both of these require Drupal, which doesn't work as we are running Wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Under Actions use the Export as CSV for the event and the members reports. Then copy and paste the one list with the other and sort them however you want. I know it is not one simple step within Civi but it should get you what you are looking for.

Comment: Not really. I don't want a manual process, I want a report that a non-technical user can print for the meeting

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can do this with the constituent detail report under contact reports.

First of all, I think you need to create a temporary group with the people you are interested in. Find the participants for the event you want and add them to the temp group. Then find the contacts in the group you are are interested in and add them to the temp group.

Then in the constituent detail report filter by the temp group. In the columns selection, remove all to do with contributions and activities, add email in for the contact and select other columns as you require.

Comment: That doesn't really work either, as you don't end up with one person per row, with columns for Membership Type, Status, End Date

Comment: In which case I don't think you will find what you want in an existing report and would have to write a new report.

Comment: Ya. I find CiviReport to be quite clunky and not at all flexible, hence why I have both Extended Reports and Reports Plus enabled. Hopefully we will see a new structure come in the future that combines Search Builder-style functionality with the reports

Comment: I hesitate to write this because you cannot hear the tone, but...   CiviCRM is Open Source. Extended Reports and Reports Plus exist because someone saw a need and ran a campaign to fund a fix. Also Civi in general needs regular funding to keep improving. You might have to work within the WordPress/Civi communities to have a fix made. Please understand, I know nothing about you so this is not directly pointed at you. For all I know, you are the top donor to Civi. But I just wanted to take the opportunity to put in a plug on behalf of those that have made all of this possible so far. THANKS!